# Wordpress Multisite Database Error

Tags: database, wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

I tried setting up the multisite for WordPress, and I added the following code to my wp-config.php on my main installation.

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'my.example.site');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

My .htaccess on my main domain looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

I added the extra site as I should. It is a subdomain of a subdomain, so sub.my.example.site. Once installed, I made a subfolder in my WordPress folder, and pointed a subdomain at the folder in cPanel.

In wp-config.php on the subsite, I have the following code:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'sub.my.example.site');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', 'sub.my.example.site');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 2);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 2);
```

If I set SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL to true, it redirects to the following:

```
http://sub.my.example.sitesub.my.example.sitewp-signup.php/?new=sub.my.example.site
```

Anyone in here know how to fix this issue? The sites are set up on two different databases, and the databases are working as they should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The fix is to not create a subdirectory in your FTP, nor create a new database for the multisite.

I pointed the subdomain to the root of the website and removed the subdirectory. Everything works now.